# Proof of correctness of Bottleneck Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof

I am working on a bottleneck multicast tree for which I am using bottleneck Dijkstra algorithm.

My question is

1) bottleneck Dijkstra has the same correctness as that of (simple) Dijkstra or not ?

2) if yes then how and if no then how?

Will be happy to see your responses. Thank you